# Why does java.nio.Paths.get(..) does not take java.nio.Path objects as input?

Tags: java

I started to use `java.nio.*` and now I am wondering: Why does `java.nio.Paths.get(..)` does not take `java.nio.Path` objects as input?

Now I all the time do something like this:

```
final Path basePath = Paths.get("/some/base/path");
final Path filePath = Paths.get(basePath.toString(), "file.txt");
```

So either I've overlooked something really fundamental or the API designer completely forgot about this option, what I strongly doubt.

Comment: Why would you do that? Already having a path-object obliterates the need for Paths.get because all it does is creating a path-object.

Comment: Since `Paths.get()` converts the argument to a `Path`, there is no need to take a `Path` as the argument. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a Path into a Path? It's already a Path.

Comment: Because you are supposed to use `basePath.resolve("file.txt")` for that.  You should look through [the Path documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and become familiar with what it can do.

Comment: @SilverNak If I understand you correctly `Path.get(..)` is not the right method to build a path from different parts. What would be a better way to do that?

Comment: The method you should use, is propably `Path#resolve`, see the comment of @VGR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This class is a factory method to create `Path` objects which the intention is clearly indicated in the javadoc :

> This class consists **exclusively** of static methods that **return a Path**
>   by converting **a path string or URI**.

Which would be the goal to invoke this method if we already had a `Path` object

---

To resolve a resource `Path` from a base `Path`, you don't need to use again the `Paths` class.
`Path` methods provides operations on `Path` (comparison, `Path` creation between two `Path`s, etc..) as `Path` resolving.

```
Path resolve(Path other);
```

> Resolve the given path against this path.

Or more simply said, it creates a `Path` from two of them.

Suppose a resource located in `D:/my-resources/one-resource`

```
Path relativePathResource = Paths.get("one-resource");
Path absolutePathResource = Paths.get("D:/my-resources").resolve(resource);
```

Comment: Like in my example: I have a base path (as `Path` object) and I want to build the `Path` object of a sub-folder. Why shouldn't `Path` used for that purpose?

Comment: Because Path has already a method to do it : `resolve()`. I updated to show usage of it.